# Hide or remove category list in login page

Tags: magento2, layout, category-products

I tried to `remove or hide` the `category list` on header in **login page only**. How can i do it? I don't see anything in `customer login layout` that generate the catalog list.

Comment: do you want to remove the menu

Comment: by category list do you mean header navigation menu?

Comment: @ArunKarnawat just hide it in login page.@Piyush it's category that we can add from the backend **Catalog > Ctegories**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code in your `customer_account_login.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide the Navigation menu only in Login Page, override layout file

```
 \vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\layout\customer_account_login.xml
```

in you theme at

```
\app\<Vendor>\<ThemeName>\Magento_Customer\layout\customer_account_login.xml
```

and add

```
<referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true"/>
```

just before closing body tag `</body>`

> Do not Edit Core file as changes may be removed when you upgrade Magento version

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove top navigation menu for category from header in login page then follow below steps:

Create **customer_account_login.xml** **app\design\frontend\PackageName\ThemeName\layout** paste below code into file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```